# i am not able to install hp laserjet 1007/8 in ubuntu 12.04, please help

Tags: 12.04, hplip, laserjet

i have installed ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 in two pc earlier running in win xp.
the printer hp laser jet 1007/1008 are not detected and the problem is not solved  even after connected to internet. please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the drivers manually by downloading them from [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=2020&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=3435688)

Comment: The above link will actually redirect you to [hplip](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html?)

Comment: Very strange behavior. Long short story you have to download the specific driver (e.g. from [here](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/drivers.html)) and install manually.